# How do you NOT automatically dereference a db.ReferenceProperty in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Suppose I have

```
class Foo(db.Model):

  bar = db.ReferenceProperty(Bar)

foo = Foo.all().get()
```

Is there a way for me to do foo.bar without a query being made to Datastore? The docs say that `foo.bar` will be an instance of `Key`, so I would expect to be able to do `foo.bar.id()` and be able to get the `id` of the `Bar` that's associated with `foo`, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

PS: The part of the docs I'm referring to can be found here:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty

and it says this:

"An application can explicitly db.get() the value of a ReferenceProperty (which is a Key) to test whether the referenced entity exists."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) say,

> The ReferenceProperty value can be
>   used as if it were a model instance,
>   and the datastore entity will be
>   fetched and the model instance created
>   when it is first used in this way.
>   Untouched reference properties do not
>   query for unneeded data.

so you're fine as long as you don't touch it, but if you do though it, e.g. with an `.id()` call as you show, "the datastore entity will be fetched", the docs say.  More docs are [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entitiesandmodels.html#References), but they don't show a way to magically get the id without fetching, either.

I have not tried, but you might be able to use the [get_value_for_datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass.html#Property_get_value_for_datastore) of the property to get "the Python-native value of the property" which I believe is indeed a Key -- whose `id()` method should be callable without datastore fetches.  Have you tried that?

Comment: get_value_for_datastore is indeed the correct method - specifically, ModelClass.property.get_value_for_datastore(entity).

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I read that part of the docs too. To me, it's not clear that doing foo.bar.id() would automatically go to Datastore, because it says "as if it were a model instance". I thought it might be the case that foo.bar returned a proxy, which wouldn't automatically go to Datastore, unless it really needed to, which wouldn't be the case if I were to do foo.bar.id(), since that information is part of foo itself.

Comment: This proves that is good idea if you plan to store binary data in some kind, to split it in 2 kinds and refer to the one containing the meta data but not the binary data, because fetching smaller entities is faster the fetching larger ones.

Comment: So the call should look like `foo.bar.get_value_for_datastore().id()` ?

Comment: @Triptych I think it's `Foo.bar.get_value_for_datastore(foo).id()` where Foo is the model class, bar is the ReferenceProperty, and foo is an instance of the class. The resulting object should be a KEY: http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/cf9af7c9a5976d27/3083824e105df2cd