# How to get only a key—without loading the entity—from ReferenceProperty in GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

When ReferenceProperty is accessed it loads an entity from datastore, but sometimes I'd like only to use a referenced model key only and I don't want to pay the additional cost of referenced model loadup.

Is there a way to access just the key on a ReferenceProperty?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you NOT automatically dereference a db.ReferenceProperty in Google App Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395144/how-do-you-not-automatically-dereference-a-db-referenceproperty-in-google-app-eng)

Comment: Thx, I could not find that… probably cause that q/a is convoluted and focused on how `ReferenceProperty` does auto loading when accessed. I guess my q/a is simpler and focuses on how to just obtain the *key value* from `ReferenceProperty`—ergo easier to find

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given

```
class Foo(db.Model):
    bar = db.ReferenceProperty()
```

and

```
foo = Foo.get_by_id(1) # or however you get it
```

you can retrieve the key `foo`'s `bar` `ReferenceProperty` like so:

```
key = Foo.bar.get_value_for_datastore(foo)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I forgot that the underlying values are stored in the *_* prefixed attributes, so I guess the unsupported way would be to use `foo._bar`—need to check that.